# SQF to C# - Encryption code convertion

Tags: c#, encryption, sqf

G'Day. I am attempting to convert a function that was initially made for Bohemia Interactives language SQF to C#. The script is designed to encrypt a string with the encryption method RC4, however, it works a little bit different to the way this is traditionally done thanks to limitations of the arma3 engine. The whole idea of this is so I can encrypt a string with the C# program, and decrypt it through Arma 3 in-game.

Here is the code I am trying to convert from.

```
    /*
        Function: ALiVE_fnc_crypt
        Author(s): Naught
        Version: 1.0
        Description:
                Encrypts or decrypts a string with a specified encryption key.
        Parameters:
                0 - Decrypt (0) or encrypt (1) [number]
                1 - Encryption method name [string]
                2 - Encrypted or plain data [string]
                3 - Encryption key [string]
        Returns:
                Encrypted or decrypted data or nothing on failure [string:nil]
        Note(s):
                1. Current encryption method names:
                        - "rc4" // Rivest Cipher 4 Stream Encryption Algorithm

*/
// Constants
MAX_CHAR_SIZE = 8;
CHAR_ZERO_REP = 256;

private ["_method", "_key"];
_encText = _this select 0;
_key = _this select 1;


private ["_fnc_intToBin"];
_fnc_intToBin = {
        private ["_int", "_bin", "_pwr", "_bool"];
        _int = _this select 0;
        _bin = if ((count _this) > 1) then {_this select 1} else {[]};

        for "_i" from (MAX_CHAR_SIZE - 1) to 0 step (-1) do
        {
                _pwr = 2^(_i);
                _bool = _pwr <= _int;

                _bin set [(count _bin), _bool];

                if (_bool) then {_int = _int - _pwr};
        };

        _bin
};

private ["_bin"];
_bin = [];

// Convert string to UTF-8 binary
{ // count (faster than forEach)
        [(if (_x == CHAR_ZERO_REP) then {0} else {_x}), _bin] call _fnc_intToBin;
        false;
} count toArray(_encText);
systemChat str _bin;

// Encrypt & decrypt methods
_key = toArray(_key);

private ["_keyLen", "_state", "_temp", "_j"];
_keyLen = count _key;
_state = [];
_temp = 0;
_j = 0;

// Key-Scheduling Algorithm
for "_i" from 0 to 255 do {_state set [_i,_i]};
for "_i" from 0 to 255 do
{
        _temp = _state select _i;

        _j = (_j + _temp + (_key select (_i mod _keyLen))) mod 256;

        _state set [_i, (_state select _j)];
        _state set [_j, _temp];
};


private ["_temp1", "_temp2", "_rand", "_i", "_mod", "_rbit"];
_temp1 = 0;
_temp2 = 0;
_rand = [];
_i = 0;
_j = 0;
hint str _bin;
// Pseudo-Random Generation Algorithm
{
        _mod = _forEachIndex % MAX_CHAR_SIZE;

        if (_mod == 0) then
        {
                _i = (_i + 1) mod 256;
                _j = (_j + (_state select _i)) mod 256;

                _temp1 = _state select _i;
                _temp2 = _state select _j;

                _state set [_i, _temp2];
                _state set [_j, _temp1];

                _rand = [(_state select ((_temp1 + _temp2) mod 256))] call _fnc_intToBin;
        };

        _rbit = _rand select _mod;
        _bin set [_forEachIndex, (_x && !_rbit) || {!_x && _rbit}]; // XOR

} forEach _bin;

private ["_dec", "_buf", "_mod"];
_dec = 0;
_buf = [];

// Convert binary array to UTF-8 string
{
        _mod = _forEachIndex % MAX_CHAR_SIZE;

        if (_x) then {_dec = _dec + 2^((MAX_CHAR_SIZE - 1) - _mod)};

        if (_mod == 7) then
        {
                if (_dec == 0) then {_dec = CHAR_ZERO_REP};
                _buf set [(count _buf), _dec];
                _dec = 0;
        };
} forEach _bin;


toString(_buf)
```

I have made slight adjustments to this code, and it all still works fine in Arma 3.

Now, the converted function. I have changed about everything in this code from what my initial code was to try and get it working, so at this point, it may be completely incorrect, however, I will include it anyway.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace encrypt
{
    class Program
    {
        static public int MAX_CHAR_SIZE = 8;
        static public int CHAR_ZERO_REP = 256;
        static public int _keyLen;

        static void Main()
        {
            string[] args = new string[2];
            args[0] = "Some Random Code";
            args[1] = "4tuIc9tai";

            string text = args[0];

            // Convert the text to an array of decimal unicode || Same as toArray in arma 3
            string[] txtArray = new string[text.Length];
            txtArray = text.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
            int[] utf = getUni(txtArray);

            // Convert the key to an array of decimal unicode || Same as toArray in arma 3
            string[] keyArray = new string[args[1].Length];
            keyArray = args[1].ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
            int[] key = getUni(keyArray);

            // Debug the output
            //foreach (int i in utf){Console.Write(i); Console.Write(",");} Console.WriteLine();foreach (int i in key){Console.Write(i);Console.Write(","); }

            // Convert string to UTF-8 binary
            Dictionary<int, bool> _bin = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            foreach (int i in utf)
            {
                int _num;
                if (i == CHAR_ZERO_REP)
                {
                     _num = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    _num = i;
                }
                _bin = intToBin(_num, _bin);
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, bool> i in _bin)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToString(i.Value));
                Console.Write(", ");
            }

            // Encrypt & decrypt methods
            _keyLen = key.Length;
            int[] _state = new int[1024];
            int _temp = 0;
            int _j = 0;

            // Key-Scheduling Algorithm
            for (int _i = 0; _i < 255; _i++)
            {
                _state.SetValue(_i, _i);
            }

            for (int _i = 0; _i < 255; _i++)
            {
                _temp = _state[_i];

                _j = (_j + _temp + key[_i % _keyLen]) % 256;

                _state.SetValue(_i, _state[_j]);
                _state.SetValue(_j, _temp);
            }



            // Pseudo-Random Generation Algorithm

            int _temp1 = 0;
            int _temp2 = 0;
            Dictionary<int, bool> _rand = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            int __i = 0;
            int __j = 0;
            int indx = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < _bin.Count-1; i++)
            {
                int _mod = indx % MAX_CHAR_SIZE;

                if (_mod == 0)
                {

                    __i = (__i + 1) % 256;
                    __j = (__j + _state[__i]) % 256;

                    _temp1 = _state[__i];
                    _temp2 = _state[__j];

                    _state.SetValue(__i, _temp2);
                    _state.SetValue(__j, _temp1);

                    _rand = intToBin(_state[_temp1 + _temp2] % 256, _rand);
                }

                bool _rbit = _rand[_mod];
                bool _bit = _bin[i];
                if (_bin.ContainsKey(indx))
                {
                    _bin.Remove(indx);
                }
                _bin.Add(indx, (_bit && !_rbit) || (!_bit && _rbit));

                indx++;
            }

            // Convert binary array to UTF-8 string
            int _dec = 0;
            int[] _buf = new int[_bin.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < _bin.Count-1; i++)
            {
                int _mod = i % MAX_CHAR_SIZE;
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                if (_bin[i])
                {
                    _dec = _dec + 2 ^ ((MAX_CHAR_SIZE - 1) - _mod);
                }

                if (_mod == 7)
                {
                    if (_dec == 0)
                    {
                        _dec = CHAR_ZERO_REP;
                    }
                    _buf.SetValue(_dec, _buf.Length-1);
                    _dec = 0;
                }

                _buf.SetValue(_dec, _buf.Length - 1);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int[] getUni(string[] txtArray)
        {
            int[] ret = new int[txtArray.Length];
            int idx = 0;

            foreach (string i in txtArray)
            {
                ret.SetValue(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(i)[0], idx);
                idx++;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        static Dictionary<int, bool> intToBin(int val, Dictionary<int, bool> bin)
        {
            for (int i = MAX_CHAR_SIZE-1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int _pwr = 2 ^ i;
                bool _bool = _pwr <= val;

                int cc = bin.Count;

                if (bin.ContainsKey(cc))
                {
                    bin.Remove(cc);
                }
                bin.Add(cc, _bool);

                if (_bool)
                {
                    val = val - _pwr;
                }
            }
            return bin;
        }


    }
}
```

Any help what so ever would be great :)

Comment: Are you interested I security or just getting RC4 to work?

Comment: Let me clarify. When starting the project, my primary goal was the security. At the moment, I would just like to get this working to improve my programming knowledge. Do you know of a better way to encrypt the data?

Comment: Ok, I will go ahead and take a look at that. Thanks :)

Comment: That is a good question. Yes, use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). RC4 should not be used for new work. Additionally since AES has been the standard since 2001 and there is generally good support for it including instructions in many processors to accelerate its performance. You should find substantial information on using AES here and on the Internet in general.

Comment: For C# look at [MSDN Aes Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: So is this supposed to be RC4 or some scheme similar to RC4? If it is RC4, there are certainly existing implementations, especially at the C# side?